# Memory Crash due to [super dealloc] of uiview controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, crash

I am having a `uiviewcontroller` instance and when I am releasing it the dealloc method of it is called.

I have released some objects in dealloc method of that `uiviewcontroller`.

If I comment `[super dealloc]` the app is working fine but if don't it is crashing.

I think there is no problem with the releases that I am doing in that method, but if I do `[super dealloc]` it is crashing.

Can any one help me out with this?

Comment: Can you post error message from debugger console?

Comment: Can you post your dealloc method that contains the [super dealloc]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to tell from your post without more information, but does your dealloc method look like this?

```
- (void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];

    self.someProperty = nil;
}
```

Because if it does, you're calling a setter method on a deallocated instance. You should always call [super dealloc] last:

```
- (void)dealloc {

    self.someProperty = nil;

    [super dealloc];

}
```

Not sure if that helps. Try posting what your dealloc method looks like if not. Hard to troubleshoot in the dark.

Comment: You shouldn't access properties like that in dealloc - it's considered bad practice because you are re-entering the object which is in the process of being deallocated.  You should instead do this: [someProperty release], someProperty = nil;

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to help you without more information. The code you described is perfectly fine. The problem is in some other part of your app.

You probably access the view controller after releasing it, so the problem is not the `[super dealloc]` but any other place in you application that accesses the view controller.

Comment: This was my first thought as well. When not calling super dealloc, your object doesn't get dealloc'd and bad code elsewhere manages to still work. When you uncomment the super call, the error comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are releasing the controller in the wrong place. That could be why your [super dealloc] in your ViewController.m is crashing

You shouldn't called [viewController release] until you want that controller to die. For example, if you have an application with just a viewcontroller you must not release it until the application ends. This is because that controller needs to stay alive all the time to control the view. If you have in your ApplicationDelegate something like this, it will crash:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[window addSubview:controller.view];
[controller release]; //this will crash
}
```

Instead of that you should place your viewcontroller in the header file (.h) and release it in the dealloc method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
[controller release];
[window release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

I hope this helps.